# Disable detection of certain hardware?

Tags: linux, boot, hardware

I have a computer with two PCI TV cards. One is Compro (Win friendly), another is Leadtek (Linux friendly). Now, I'm trying to optimize my Ubuntu boot process and I would like to disable detection of my Compro card because it's not working on Linux, it won't work and even if it does, I don't care.
I sometimes use Windows so removing the Compro card is not an option. Is there any way to tell Linux "ignore any hardware placed THERE (appropriate PCI slot)"?

My dmesg concerning tv card detection looks like this:

```
1.933868] cx88/0: cx2388x v4l2 driver version 0.0.8 loaded
[    1.933885] cx8800 0000:05:01.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    1.935571] cx88[0]: Your board isn't known (yet) to the driver.  You can
[    1.935573] cx88[0]: try to pick one of the existing card configs via
[    1.935574] cx88[0]: card=<n> insmod option.  Updating to the latest
[    1.935575] cx88[0]: version might help as well.
[    1.936574] cx88[0]: Here is a list of valid choices for the card=<n> insmod option:
[    1.936890] cx88[0]:    card=0 -> UNKNOWN/GENERIC
[    1.937089] cx88[0]:    card=1 -> Hauppauge WinTV 34xxx models
[    1.937328] cx88[0]:    card=2 -> GDI Black Gold
[    1.937519] cx88[0]:    card=3 -> PixelView
[    1.937690] cx88[0]:    card=4 -> ATI TV Wonder Pro
[    1.937890] cx88[0]:    card=5 -> Leadtek Winfast 2000XP Expert
[    1.938137] cx88[0]:    card=6 -> AverTV Studio 303 (M126)
[    1.938366] cx88[0]:    card=7 -> MSI TV-@nywhere Master
[    1.938586] cx88[0]:    card=8 -> Leadtek Winfast DV2000
[    1.938803] cx88[0]:    card=9 -> Leadtek PVR 2000
[    1.939004] cx88[0]:    card=10 -> IODATA GV-VCP3/PCI
[    1.939211] cx88[0]:    card=11 -> Prolink PlayTV PVR
[    1.939417] cx88[0]:    card=12 -> ASUS PVR-416
[    1.939603] cx88[0]:    card=13 -> MSI TV-@nywhere
[    1.939799] cx88[0]:    card=14 -> KWorld/VStream XPert DVB-T
[    1.940040] cx88[0]:    card=15 -> DViCO FusionHDTV DVB-T1
[    1.940264] cx88[0]:    card=16 -> KWorld LTV883RF
[    1.940460] cx88[0]:    card=17 -> DViCO FusionHDTV 3 Gold-Q
[    1.940691] cx88[0]:    card=18 -> Hauppauge Nova-T DVB-T
[    1.940917] cx88[0]:    card=19 -> Conexant DVB-T reference design
[    1.941174] cx88[0]:    card=20 -> Provideo PV259
[    1.941367] cx88[0]:    card=21 -> DViCO FusionHDTV DVB-T Plus
[    1.941605] cx88[0]:    card=22 -> pcHDTV HD3000 HDTV
[    1.941812] cx88[0]:    card=23 -> digitalnow DNTV Live! DVB-T
[    1.942055] cx88[0]:    card=24 -> Hauppauge WinTV 28xxx (Roslyn) models
[    1.942329] cx88[0]:    card=25 -> Digital-Logic MICROSPACE Entertainment Center (MEC)
[    1.942651] cx88[0]:    card=26 -> IODATA GV/BCTV7E
[    1.942851] cx88[0]:    card=27 -> PixelView PlayTV Ultra Pro (Stereo)
[    1.943123] cx88[0]:    card=28 -> DViCO FusionHDTV 3 Gold-T
[    1.943354] cx88[0]:    card=29 -> ADS Tech Instant TV DVB-T PCI
[    1.943599] cx88[0]:    card=30 -> TerraTec Cinergy 1400 DVB-T
[    1.943842] cx88[0]:    card=31 -> DViCO FusionHDTV 5 Gold
[    1.944075] cx88[0]:    card=32 -> AverMedia UltraTV Media Center PCI 550
[    1.944352] cx88[0]:    card=33 -> Kworld V-Stream Xpert DVD
[    1.944584] cx88[0]:    card=34 -> ATI HDTV Wonder
[    1.944779] cx88[0]:    card=35 -> WinFast DTV1000-T
[    1.944982] cx88[0]:    card=36 -> AVerTV 303 (M126)
[    1.945191] cx88[0]:    card=37 -> Hauppauge Nova-S-Plus DVB-S
[    1.945430] cx88[0]:    card=38 -> Hauppauge Nova-SE2 DVB-S
[    1.945657] cx88[0]:    card=39 -> KWorld DVB-S 100
[    1.945857] cx88[0]:    card=40 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR1100 DVB-T/Hybrid
[    1.946132] cx88[0]:    card=41 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR1100 DVB-T/Hybrid (Low Profile)
[    1.946452] cx88[0]:    card=42 -> digitalnow DNTV Live! DVB-T Pro
[    1.952195] cx88[0]:    card=43 -> KWorld/VStream XPert DVB-T with cx22702
[    1.952253] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[    1.957988] cx88[0]:    card=44 -> DViCO FusionHDTV DVB-T Dual Digital
[    1.963725] cx88[0]:    card=45 -> KWorld HardwareMpegTV XPert
[    1.969424] cx88[0]:    card=46 -> DViCO FusionHDTV DVB-T Hybrid
[    1.975040] cx88[0]:    card=47 -> pcHDTV HD5500 HDTV
[    1.980535] cx88[0]:    card=48 -> Kworld MCE 200 Deluxe
[    1.986008] cx88[0]:    card=49 -> PixelView PlayTV P7000
[    1.991482] cx88[0]:    card=50 -> NPG Tech Real TV FM Top 10
[    1.997005] cx88[0]:    card=51 -> WinFast DTV2000 H
[    2.002538] cx88[0]:    card=52 -> Geniatech DVB-S
[    2.008027] cx88[0]:    card=53 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR3000 TriMode Analog/DVB-S/DVB-T
[    2.013714] cx88[0]:    card=54 -> Norwood Micro TV Tuner
[    2.019407] cx88[0]:    card=55 -> Shenzhen Tungsten Ages Tech TE-DTV-250 / Swann OEM
[    2.025299] cx88[0]:    card=56 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR1300 DVB-T/Hybrid MPEG Encoder
[    2.031338] cx88[0]:    card=57 -> ADS Tech Instant Video PCI
[    2.037373] cx88[0]:    card=58 -> Pinnacle PCTV HD 800i
[    2.043379] cx88[0]:    card=59 -> DViCO FusionHDTV 5 PCI nano
[    2.049444] cx88[0]:    card=60 -> Pinnacle Hybrid PCTV
[    2.055525] cx88[0]:    card=61 -> Leadtek TV2000 XP Global
[    2.061631] cx88[0]:    card=62 -> PowerColor RA330
[    2.067686] cx88[0]:    card=63 -> Geniatech X8000-MT DVBT
[    2.073779] cx88[0]:    card=64 -> DViCO FusionHDTV DVB-T PRO
[    2.079891] cx88[0]:    card=65 -> DViCO FusionHDTV 7 Gold
[    2.085954] cx88[0]:    card=66 -> Prolink Pixelview MPEG 8000GT
[    2.092031] cx88[0]:    card=67 -> Kworld PlusTV HD PCI 120 (ATSC 120)
[    2.098160] cx88[0]:    card=68 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR4000 DVB-S/S2/T/Hybrid
[    2.104363] cx88[0]:    card=69 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR4000(Lite) DVB-S/S2
[    2.104366] cx88[0]:    card=70 -> TeVii S460 DVB-S/S2
[    2.104368] cx88[0]:    card=71 -> Omicom SS4 DVB-S/S2 PCI
[    2.104370] cx88[0]:    card=72 -> TBS 8920 DVB-S/S2
[    2.104372] cx88[0]:    card=73 -> TeVii S420 DVB-S
[    2.104374] cx88[0]:    card=74 -> Prolink Pixelview Global Extreme
[    2.104375] cx88[0]:    card=75 -> PROF 7300 DVB-S/S2
[    2.104377] cx88[0]:    card=76 -> SATTRADE ST4200 DVB-S/S2
[    2.104379] cx88[0]:    card=77 -> TBS 8910 DVB-S
[    2.104381] cx88[0]:    card=78 -> Prof 6200 DVB-S
[    2.104383] cx88[0]:    card=79 -> Terratec Cinergy HT PCI MKII
[    2.104384] cx88[0]:    card=80 -> Hauppauge WinTV-IR Only
[    2.104386] cx88[0]:    card=81 -> Leadtek WinFast DTV1800 Hybrid
[    2.104388] cx88[0]:    card=82 -> WinFast DTV2000 H rev. J
[    2.104390] cx88[0]:    card=83 -> Prof 7301 DVB-S/S2
[    2.104392] cx88[0]:    card=84 -> Samsung SMT 7020 DVB-S
[    2.104394] cx88[0]:    card=85 -> Twinhan VP-1027 DVB-S
[    2.104395] cx88[0]:    card=86 -> TeVii S464 DVB-S/S2
[    2.104398] cx88[0]: subsystem: 185b:e000, board: UNKNOWN/GENERIC [card=0,autodetected], frontend(s): 0
[    2.104401] cx88[0]: TV tuner type -1, Radio tuner type -1
```

I know, I won't see any speedup benefit from disabling that detection, but those lines appear before plymouth splash and I don't like it :\

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable a device, you can blacklist its kernel module by using the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file.

If you want to disable detection and completely ignore a device, then you should disable the related PCI port, usually from your BIOS. If you want Linux to ignore your BIOS enabled device, you may probably need to patch your kernel.

See the similar questions on Ask Ubuntu and SO:

- [How do I turn off PCI devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4546/how-do-i-turn-off-pci-devices)
- [Can I completely disable a PCI-slot in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117465/can-i-completely-disable-a-pci-slot-in-linux)

Comment: Can't disable kernel module because it's already used by WORKING Linux tv card :\ I would like to patch my kernel so i can ignore that specific PCI port but how to do it? I have compiled my current kernel, but i have never patched one...